# Automating and filtering data from one sheet in Excel to four different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two separate sheets in Excel that shows data in the form of (O) and (T). They will be further separated in to four sheets named A, B, N, S.

How do I go about automating data keyed in the first sheet that will automatically go into the 4 sheets (A/B/N/S) respectively and arranged as (O) and (T)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.